# Linq to Entities Group by followed by Min

Tags: entity-framework, group-by, linq-to-entities

I want to write the following SQL as a Linq to Entities statement

```
select min(enddate), Code 
from t1
inner join t2
on t1.t2id = t2.id
group by Code
```

What I have so far is

```
var data = ctx.t1.Join(ctx.t2,
                        one => one.t2id,
                        two => two.Id,
                        (one, two) => new {one, two})
                    .GroupBy(onetwo => onetwo.one.t2id)
                    .Min(onetwo => WHAT GOES HERE?);
```

I think the only thing I am missing is what goes in `WHAT GOES HERE?`.  I could be wrong and have gone totally astray but as far as I know this is the only thing I am missing.  Any idea what I can do?

Comment: You want a `Select` not a `Min` otherwise you will only be able to return a single value.

Comment: Ok, then can you tell me what that might look like?

Comment: Something like: `.Select(x => new { Code = x.Key, MinDate = x.Min()})`

Comment: Although I think I might need to specify that it's the Min of the EndDate column that I need somewhere right?

Comment: Ah yes, so `Min(g => g.one.EndDate)` (not sure which table `EndDate` is part of)

Comment: Don't do this with `Join()`. First create a navigation property between `t1` and `t2`. After that it's ridiculously simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be using is a `Select` not a `Min`,  otherwise you will only be able to return a single value. For example, something like this:

```
var data = ctx.t1
    .Join(ctx.t2, one => one.t2id, two => two.Id, (one, two) => new {one, two})
    .GroupBy(onetwo => onetwo.one.t2id)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        Code = x.Key, 
        MinDate = x.Min(g => g.one.EndDate) //This may need to be g.two.EndDate
    });
```

Comment: It is one but there is no one in g.  I think I need to cast?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. What data type is `EndDate`?

Comment: It's a DateTime.  I mean I might need a cast on g so that one and two might be available on it.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking now. The LINQ I show will give you the same output as your SQL.